# Django change url pattern

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

My url pattern :

```
path('business/average/turnover/<str:start_date>/<str:end_date>/', views.AverageTurnover.as_view())
```

when go to the url it shows something like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/average/turnover/2019-01-1/2019-12-12/
```

but i want it to be like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/business?start_date=adfadf&end_date=xsdfa
```

How to do this.

Note:
I have no view function is rendering this url but when i am directly hitting this url then it goes to views like this.

views.py

```
class AverageTurnover(APIView):
    '''Average Turn Over'''

    def get(self, request, start_date, end_date):
        avg_turnover = BusinessShareInfo.objects.filter(Date__range=(start_date, end_date)).aggregate(Avg('Turnover'))
        return Response(avg_turnover)
```

Comment: what about views.py?

Comment: Biplove updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to receive `GET` request in your view. This is how you can achieve what you want but still I would recommend going that way it is cleaner.

Nevertheless here are the changes you will need to do.

- Change your url to

```
path('business/', views.AverageTurnover.as_view())
```

- Change your `views.py` so it can handle `GET` requests (you can learn about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/))
- Also remember to add form in template. (you can learn about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/))

> Note: Remember to use `GET` request method as it passes the data in the url and this is what you want. You do not want to use `POST` request method as it does not passes data in url (a lot cleaner)

You are doing it wrong, I suggest you to read the resources I mentioned. The way you taking arguments will require you have this type of url,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/average/turnover/2019-01-1/2019-12-12/
```

If you will use `GET` method properly you can change it to,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/business?start_date=adfadf&end_date=xsdfa
```

Comment: my get request function is taking two arguments.Sir please see views.py i have updated.

Answer (score 0):

class AverageTurnover(generics.RetriveAPIView):
    '''Average Turn Over'''

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
    avg_turnover = BusinessShareInfo.objects.filter(Date__range=(start_date, end_date)).aggregate(Avg('Turnover'))
    return Response(avg_turnover)
```

Then use the url @Hisham__Pak and when invoking this api just pass the query params as you mentioned.

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/business?start_date=adfadf&end_date=xsdfa

Comment: I will see and let you know.Thanks